# test multiple spring boot services at once

Tags: spring, docker, testing

I have 10 spring boot services and they all communicate with 11th spring boot service via rabbitmq. I want to set up a test environment where I can run all services, see records in db, and, ideally, mock external services requests (aka maxmind, etc). How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't get the question right but just install it in an test environment?

You can do that with things like docker/kubernetes or if you prefer just start your services on different ports and route it by yourself.

For mocks just write a simple spring boot microservice that takes requests and responds with the data you need for your tests.

Comment: I mean is there any ready-to-go solution which has ready rabbit, mariadb, mongo and other tools installed?

Comment: In other words, I start ONE container where all tools + all my services are running

Comment: I think docker compose can help you to solve problem

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. But frameworks like [Citrus](https://citrusframework.org/) or [Lagom](https://www.lagomframework.com/) also might help to get what you want.